# Google Apps Script to remove file / folder permissions for specific user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a script to remove all sharing permission for a specific user for all files or folders within Google Drive. The script for the files is more or less working even when at the end I get an error, but the script for the folder is not.

For the files:

```js
function RemoveFiles() {
  const EDITOR = "remove@test.com";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.revokePermissions(EDITOR);
  }
}
```

For the folders:

```js
function RemoveFolders() {
  const EDITOR = "remove@test.com";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.removeEditor(EDITOR);
    folder.removeViewer(EDITOR);
  }
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does `but the script for the folder is not.` mean? Does an error occur?

Comment: Exception: No such user
RemoveFolders
@ Code:gs:6

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, yes this worked. Now I just wanted to double-check the files script, and it isn't working any longer. Strange. Can I adjust the files script the same way if there is any sharing on a file (viewer, editor, comments) it should simply revoke every permission?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `yes this worked.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Now I just wanted to double-check the files script, and it isn't working any longer. Strange. Can I adjust the files script the same way if there is any sharing on a file (viewer, editor, comments) it should simply revoke every permission?`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Exception: No such user RemoveFolders @ Code:gs:6` in your reply, in your script, how about the following modification? In your script of `RemoveFiles()`, `searchFiles` is used. In this modification, `searchFolders` is used.

#### Modified script:

```js
function RemoveFolders() {
  const EDITOR = "remove@test.com";
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.removeEditor(EDITOR);
  }
}
```

- By this modification, the folders that `remove@test.com` is shared as a writer are retrieved. And, `remove@test.com` is removed from the folders.
- If you want to remove both Viewers and Editors from `remove@test.com`, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function RemoveFolders() {
    const EDITOR = "remove@test.com";
    var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(`('${EDITOR}' in writers or '${EDITOR}' in readers) and trashed=false`);
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      try {
        if (folder.getViewers().find(e => e.getEmail() == EDITOR)) {
          folder.removeViewer(EDITOR);
        }
        if (folder.getEditors().find(e => e.getEmail() == EDITOR)) {
          folder.removeEditor(EDITOR);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // console.log(e) // If you want to confirm the error, please use this.
      }
    }
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [searchFolders(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfoldersparams)

### Added:

From your following additional request,

> yes this worked. Now I just wanted to double-check the files script, and it isn't working any longer. Strange. Can I adjust the files script the same way if there is any sharing on a file (viewer, editor, comments) it should simply revoke every permission?
> In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function RemoveFiles() {
  const EDITOR = "remove@test.com";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`('${EDITOR}' in writers or '${EDITOR}' in readers) and trashed=false`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    try {
      if (file.getViewers().find(e => e.getEmail() == EDITOR)) {
        file.removeViewer(EDITOR);
      }
      if (file.getEditors().find(e => e.getEmail() == EDITOR)) {
        file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // console.log(e) // If you want to confirm the error, please use this.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the Files and Folders script and strangely for both I get an error:

Exception: Invalid argument
RemoveFiles @ Code.gs:4

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. About `I tried the Files and Folders script and strangely for both I get an error: Exception: Invalid argument RemoveFiles @ Code.gs:4`, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot know your actual situation because of my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill. But, I'm worried that about those files and folders, you might have no permission. So, as a simple modification, how about using try-catch? I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @x0100 Now, I updated the above scripts using try-catch. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thx for the adjustment but just a quick question, what can i do with "console.log(e)" and how can i get the logs?

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from the current situation and your reply of `Thx for the adjustment but just a quick question, what can i do with "console.log(e)" and how can i get the logs?`, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Before I think of your new question, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I created the projects new, in a new Google Drive and now both are working fine. The script for the files and for the folders. Thanks a lot.
Just one more question, I made some test shares with editor, commenter, viewer.
Even in your script you are just checking for editor & viewer, the commenter gets removed too. Why is this the case?

Comment: @x0100 From `I created the projects new, in a new Google Drive and now both are working fine. The script for the files and for the folders.`, I understood that your question was resolved.

Comment: @x0100 About your additional question of `Just one more question, I made some test shares with the editor, commenter, and viewer. Even in your script, you are just checking for editor & viewer, the commenter gets removed too. Why is this the case?`, it seems that `getViewers()` includes the viewers and the commenters. And, the method of `getCommenters` is not existing, while the methods of `addCommenter` and `removeCommenter` are existing. I guessed that this situation might be the reason for it.

Comment: @x0100 But, if you want to remove only the commenter, when Drive API is used, the commenters can be retrieved. Using this, only commenters can be removed by `removeCommenter`. If this explanation of your additional question was not useful, I apologize.